# Se eu conseguir 2 perguntas com 1000 views, eu ganho dois badges de "Popular Question"?

Tags: support, questions, badges

If I have 2 questions with 1000 views, will I have 2 Popular Question badges?

Which question with 1000 views is one more popular badge?

Comment: Yes, you will have 2 [Popular Question](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=1519) badges.